# How do I save passwords and usernames to a .txt file in c++. I still want to be able to retrieve them if the user tries to login

Tags: c++, text-files

I'm starting a console based online bank(for fun). I was wondering how I would save usernames and passwords of people registering an account(perhaps a .txt file?). I was also wondering how I would go about checking the .txt file for the username and password when they attempt to log in. Any help is appreciated. Here is the source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;

// global variables
string EntryChoice;
int numberOfIncorrect = 5;
string NewUsername;
string NewPassword;
string LoginUsername;
string LoginPassword;
string NewFirstName;
string LoginFirstName;
string NewLastName;
string LoginLastName;
int Newage;
string Newgender;
int Loginage;
string LoginGender;
//declaration of functions
void Login();
void SignUp();
void BankCheck();
void BankError();
void Bank()
{

    cout << "Welcome to the Bank of National Arabs\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "|To Sign Up type (Register) then Press Enter|\n";
    cout << "|To Login type (Login) then Press Enter|\n";
    cin >> EntryChoice;
    BankCheck();
}
void BankCheck()
{
    if (EntryChoice == "Login" || EntryChoice == "LOGIN" || EntryChoice == "login")
    {
        Login();
    }
    else if (EntryChoice == "REGISTER" || EntryChoice == "register" || EntryChoice == "Register")
    {
        SignUp();
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        BankError();
    }
}
void BankError()
{
    if (numberOfIncorrect == 1)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    numberOfIncorrect -= 1;
    cout << "Welcome to the Bank of National Arabs\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "|To Sign Up type (Register) then Press Enter|\n";
    cout << "|To Login type (Login) then Press Enter|\n";
    cout << "|ERROR| " << numberOfIncorrect << " Tries Left >> ";
    cin >> EntryChoice;
    BankCheck();
}
void Login()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Bank of United Arabs Login Page\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> LoginUsername;
    cout << "\nPassword:";
    cin >> LoginPassword;

}
void SignUp()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Welcome to the Register Page\n";
    cout << "----------------------------\n";
    cout << "Age: ";
    cin >> Newage;
    cout << "\nGender: ";
    cin >> Newgender;
    cout << "\nFirst name";
    cin >> NewFirstName;
    cout << "\nLast Name";
    cin >> NewLastName;
    cout << "\nUsername: ";
    cin >> NewUsername;
    cout << "\nPassword";
    cin >> NewPassword;
}
int main()
{
        Bank();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to study this or similar: https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/

Comment: Do you mean a sort of cryptography or how to read and write a .txt in c++?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to save a users input, when they register. Then if they try to login it looks if the username and password they entered matched the ones they registered. If that makes sense.

Comment: It should be noted that in practice user passwords should be stored only by way of the hash value passed through a [one-way hash function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification). When a user tries to log in their input is passed through the same hash function and compared to the stored hash value. **Never** should user passwords be stored directly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so. Probably, everytime you input data from the user while registering, you can simultaneously store it into a txt file using c++ file operators(Read this : https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/fstream_input_output.php ), followed by a delimiter to mark the end of each individual record.
Keep the format in the text file as :

```
UserID1
Username1
Password1@
UserID2
Username2
Password2@
```

Here @ is a delimiter.
For retrieving the records search for the username or id in the .txt file by reading records using the above delimiter. If the record is found, separate the record values by line and store them in a variable and then compare with the input data values. Continue searching till the EOF flag is false.

Comment: Thanks so much I'll check it out!